# Can’t launch Firefox on OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, firefox, osx-snow-leopard

When I try to run Firefox 3.6 or 4 beta I get a message saying:

```
Profile Missing
Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded.  It may be missing or inaccessible.
```

I have tried running the profile manger from the command line using:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -ProfileManager
```

I get the same message in the popup, but I also get:

```
Error: Access was denied while trying to open files in your profile directory.
```

I have tried deleting Firefox and reinstalling it.  I have also tried deleting anything related to Firefox or Mozilla in the ~/Library/Application Support directories, but nothing seems to help.  In addition I have run the disk utility to fix any permissions issues.

If I create a new profile or run the command with `sudo`, it works.  It seems that that Firefox is trying to put the profile somewhere it doesn’t have access to write, but I can’t figure out how to change this location or change the permissions.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your account allowed to make administrative changes on the machine?  Did you install Firefox as the same user as you're now trying to run it under?

Answer (score 1):

A command was posted on the [Firefox Help forum](http://support.mozilla.com/my/questions/785562) which works well to solve this problem:

> Run this command in terminal from your
> home directory:
>
> ```
> sudo chown -R `id -un`:`id -gn` ~
> ```

Give it a try. Your Mac will ask for your admin password which scared me a little. Firefox 4 works fine now on my MacBook Pro with OS X 10.6.7.

Answer (score 1):

Cheng's response is a command that changes everything in your home directory to be owned by you. On my machine I only needed to do:

```
    sudo chown -R `id -un`:`id -gn` ~/Library/Caches
```

chown means 'change owner' and the '-R' means recursive

id is a command that returns your username with '-un' and your group name with '-gn'.

Answer (score 0):

A low-rep user ([Max2002](https://superuser.com/users/501864/max2002)) offered
this suggestion:

> I had a user that had Firefox 41.0 getting the error. 
>   It turns out that the `Caches` folder within `Library` was not there. 
>   There was a shortcut with the same name in its place. 
>   I deleted the shortcut and Shazam! problem solved. 
>   Running Firefox created the proper folder and the user could open Firefox!